# Seeking open source framework or SDK for working with nautical charts (ENCs)?

Tags: open-source, library, gis, sdk

I have to start working on a project in which I will have to work on ENCs. I was searching for the open source sdks or frameworks to work with, and came across [QGIS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/QGIS); is it good for working with ENC?

I will be working with S-57 data and will need to add multiple layer to it and that is also programmatically. I am new on this ground.

Comment: Your Question is vague. Exactly what does “work on ENCs” mean? What features and behaviors do you require?

Comment: @BasilBourque, thanks, Actually I would like to know the best opensource mapping tool that also has good support for S-57 data